# How many people have installed my app as a result of Facebook ads?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I've followed the instructions on this page for my Xcode project (ios app): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

- installed the Facebook SDK for iOS
- obtained Facebook App ID
- configured Xcode project
- archived Xcode proj, submitted to Apple, approved and live

And I've created and run ads for app installs however how do I know how many people have installed my app as a result of the ads? There is nothing showing top left of the ads page....just zero???? Nothing showing in my Facebook Developer account.

I've clearly missed a pretty obvious step...can someone please shed some light?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not calling `[FBAppEvents activateApp]` on `applicationDidBecomeActive:`.

Check also if you have a `FacebookAppID` key on your target's `Info.plist`.

You `AppDelegate` needs to look like this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <FacebookSDK.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // stuff

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBAppEvents activateApp];
}

@end
```

Comment: I definitely have the FacebookAppID in the Info.plist file. However, you may need to explain the first comment further if possible. I am not a coder/developer - I have simply followed instructions to successfully get my app up in iTunes (http://bit.ly/1c6dTmY).

Comment: I've added this line: `#import "FacebookSDK.h"` to the `AppDelegate.m` file but it immediately comes up with an error that it can't find the file even though I can see the `FacebookSDK.h` file right in front of me just a few files down the list.